# R dedupe records that are not exactly duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates, data-cleaning

I have a list of record that I need to dedup, these look like a combination of the same set of, but using the regular functions to deduplicate records does not work because the two columns are not duplicates.  Below is a reproducible example.

```
df <- data.frame( A  =  c("2","2","2","43","43","43","331","391","481","490","501","501","501","502","502","502"),

          B =  c("43","501","502","2","501","502","491","496","490","481","2","43","502","2","43","501"))
```

Below is the desired output that I'm looking for.

```
df_Final <- data.frame( A  =  c("2","2","2","331","391","481"),

          B =  c("43","501","502","491","496","490"))
```

Comment: There is no obvious tie between your input and intended output. For example, what happens to `A="43"` entries? Though it is clear you want to deduplicate, the logic behind it is certainly not intuitive or easily inferrable from your data. If you don't have clearly defined rules, then perhaps go through your input data row-by-row and explain why the row is retained or discarded.

Comment: What is the rule for deciding which vector "keeps" the value? Why does "2" belong in A and "43" belong in B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the idea is that you want to find when the elements in column `A` first appear in column `B`

```
idx = match(df$A, df$B)
```

and keep the row if the element in `A` isn't in `B` (`is.na(idx)`) or the element in `A` occurs before it's first occurrence in `B` (`seq_along(idx) < idx`)

```
df[is.na(idx) | seq_along(idx) < idx,]
```

Maybe a more-or-less literal tidyverse approach to this would be to create and then drop a temporary column

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(idx = match(A, B)) %>%
    filter(is.na(idx) | seq_along(idx) < idx) %>%
    select(-idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all rows which would be duplicates under some reordering with

```
require(dplyr)
df %>%
    apply(1, sort) %>% t %>% 
    data.frame %>% 
    group_by_all %>% 
    slice(1)
```